# Android Studio - "ndk-build" is not a recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to install ARToolKit in Android Studio and followed instructions as to how to set it up. I am at the point where I will type some commands in the terminal part but when I need to type 'ndk-build' it just says

```
C:\Users\Arjay Angelo\AndroidStudioProjects\ARSimpleNativeCarsProj\aRSimpleNativeCars\src\main>ndk-build
'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have followed every step in the tutorials and I'm stuck at this point. Even typing the 'clear' command is not recognized either. Here is the youtube link that I've been watching:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVJ5z6m4cvY
```

Really need help with this as I'm trying to develop an Augmented Reality app in android.

Comment: Since you're on Windows you might want to use `ndk-build.cmd`

Comment: Still doesn't work @Michael

Answer (score 0):

Have you add NDK to path?  locate your NDK installation path and add it to system path variable should help.